# How can I check when a PSN gift card “top-up card” got used? (Or maybe other meta data about its use.)

Tags: psn

I got a Playstation Network “gift card” code, whose code got used before I did. Is there any official or unofficial way to see *when* that code got used? Or how much that code was initially worth? Or on what account that code got used on?

Can (some) code sellers grab that information on non-public channels?

Comment: Theres probably a backdoor or something but I would guess nothing official.